# How to query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm querying the public dataset `bigquery-public-data` for its view metadata with the following query -

```
SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS`
```

but I get the following error :

```
Access Denied: Table bigquery-public-data:region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS: User does not have permission to query table bigquery-public-data:region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS, or perhaps it does not exist in location US.
```

If I query the following :-

```
SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_trends.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE`
```

I get the following error

```
Invalid project ID 'bigquery-public-data.google_trends'. Project IDs must contain 6-63 lowercase letters, digits, or dashes. Some project IDs also include domain name separated by a colon. IDs must start with a letter and may not end with a dash.
```

I've followed the instruction on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-views) and [this page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-table-storage) and it's supposed to work. Public projects such as this one have the `roles/bigquery.dataViewer` permission which is what you need to query this dataset. So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Following query is working: `SELECT * FROM  \`bigquery-public-data.baseball.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES\` `   and `SELECT * FROM \`bigquery-public-data.baseball.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS\` `

Comment: this syntax works on a normal dataset but not the public one:  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data`.`region-US`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE
WHERE table_schema = 'google_trends';

Comment: @smoore4 - this query is not working on my own dataset. I get the Access denied error that's mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Samuel - your first query works, but the 2nd query gives me no results, just a "There is no data to display" message in the results section.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to list all the datasets for the public BigQuery project (`bigquery-public-data`). When doing that, you need to have permissions on that project ([link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables)), which you don't have.

> For queries with a region qualifier, you must have permissions for the project.

If you specify a public dataset name, you'll be able to query the schema information, since you do have the necessary permissions there.

> SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_311.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

[image]

Comment: Got it, thanks! I thought I had dataViewer role for the project, but apparently, that's just for the dataset. However, when I query my own private dataset or the austin_311 dataset for INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS, I get no results. No error, but 0 results. Any idea why?

Comment: Also, is there a reason why SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_311.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE` won't work? It gives me this error :

`Invalid project ID 'bigquery-public-data.austin_311'. Project IDs must contain 6-63 lowercase letters, digits, or dashes. Some project IDs also include domain name separated by a colon. IDs must start with a letter and may not end with a dash.`

Comment: Make sure you're using the current BigQuery mode, not "legacy SQL", since they use different table name syntaxes.

Comment: Yeah, Standarad SQL is on by default. You have to check "Legacy" by going to query settings -> Advanced Options to use legacy SQL, but I've verified that it's unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

`TABLE_STORAGE` works on my Replication with my own sample datasets:
`` SELECT * FROM myProject.`region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE; ``

Output:
[image]

Here is my result for `VIEWS`
`SELECT * FROM myDataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS;`

Output:
[image]

If your result is empty it must mean that there is no view table within the scope of your query. Also please be reminded that these queries may require region qualifiers, and permissions of bigquery.tables.get/list which included in these predefined roles:

- roles/bigquery.admin
- roles/bigquery.dataEditor
- roles/bigquery.metadataViewer
- roles/bigquery.dataViewer

Also As @smoore4 mentioned `TABLE_STORAGE`  does not worked in public datasets.

For references: 
[TABLE_STORAGE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-table-storage) *Is currently in preview stage.
[VIEWS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-views)

Comment: I checked again and I'm still getting the error : - `Invalid project ID 'my-project.my_dataset'. Project IDs must contain 6-63 lowercase letters, digits, or dashes. Some project IDs also include domain name separated by a colon. IDs must start with a letter and may not end with a dash.`  

Might TABLE_STORAGE being in preview have something to do with the failure in querying it? The docs only say that the feature is covered under pre-GA offering terms.

Comment: The preview stage might be it. But just to be sure, can you share your whole query and if possible the region of your dataset situated in ?  Can you also try ```my-project.`region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE;```

Comment: I tried SELECT * FROM `abcdefgh-6aab4.region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE` but I get the Access Denied error that's mentioned in the question. I've changed the letter and number at each position in the project id here by a different letter and number, but the rest of it is as is. This is despite me being the owner of the dataset. Since you're able to use the preview features, do you have any special permissions/privileges with regards to BigQuery?

Comment: I see, Thanks for the query. In the ```region-us```, It must look like this ```abcdefgh-6aab4.`region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE```. I have the owner role as well.

Comment: I've tried that, but the issue is the the "-" in the project id is not accepted without the "``" enclosure. The purpose of the "``" enclosure simply seems to be to accept the whole of the inside as a string and not treat any special characters except the dot(.) as special characters.

Comment: That is indeed interesting, I was able query with my project having a "-" but not enclosed with any symbols with : ```SELECT * FROM my-project.`region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE``` double check the project id you might be accessing a different project that causing the permission denied error.  Even then enclosing the project id with back tick works too: `SELECT * FROM \`my-project\`.\`region-us\`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE`

Comment: I think the reason you're able to use 'my-project' without quotes is because the part after the '-' starts with a letter, which is a valid use case for Bigquery [identifiers](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#identifier_examples) whereas the part after '-' in my project name starts with a number. I thought the table being in preview stage might mean that it's not available for use in an old project, but even in a freshly created project, I'm getting the same error.